# Determine column azure query result is from

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
var keyQuery = await MobileService.GetTable<Churches>()
                                              .Where(item => item.CK_One == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Two == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Three == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Four == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Five == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Six == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Seven == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Eight == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Nine == keyEntry.Text || item.CK_Ten == keyEntry.Text)
                                                .ToEnumerableAsync();
```

It searches ten different azure table columns for a match to the text entered by the user, how can I find out which of the ten columns the result came from?

This class defines Churches:

```
using System;
namespace ChurchBuilder
{
    public class Churches
    {

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Church_Name { get; set; }
        public bool Bulletin_Page { get; set; }
        public bool Prayer_Page { get; set; }
        public bool Sermons_Page { get; set; }
        public bool Events_Page { get; set; }
        public bool Messaging_Page { get; set; }
        public bool Alert_Bar { get; set; }
        public bool Push_Notifications { get; set; }
        public string Master_Admin_Key { get; set; }
        public string Admin_Key { get; set; }
        public string Member_Key { get; set; }
        public string CK_One { get; set; }
        public string SA_One { get; set; }
        public string CK_Two { get; set; }
        public string SA_Two { get; set; }
        public string CK_Three { get; set; }
        public string SA_Three { get; set; }
        public string CK_Four { get; set; }
        public string SA_Four { get; set; }
        public string CK_Five { get; set; }
        public string SA_Five { get; set; }
        public string CK_Six { get; set; }
        public string SA_Six { get; set; }
        public string CK_Seven { get; set; }
        public string SA_Seven { get; set; }
        public string CK_Eight { get; set; }
        public string SA_Eight { get; set; }
        public string CK_Nine { get; set; }
        public string SA_Nine { get; set; }
        public string CK_Ten { get; set; }
        public string SA_Ten { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public double CostPerMonth { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageOne { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageTwo { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageThree { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageFour { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageFive { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageSix { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageSeven { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageEight { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageNine { get; set; }
        public bool RolePageTen { get; set; }
        public int Custom_Roles { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_One { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Two { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Three { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Four { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Five { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Six { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Seven { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Eight { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Nine { get; set; }
        public string Custom_Name_Ten { get; set; }

        public Churches()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little more tricky. Is the query expected to return multiple results(rows) or just one?

Comment: @Nkosi its meant to return just one

Comment: Off the top of my head I am thinking you get the record then you can use reflection to match the key and that should be able to give your the property/column name that was matched.

Comment: @Nkosi can you give me an example

Comment: Update the question to include the `Churches` definition.

Comment: @Nkosi Churches is defined through a class called churches

Comment: Show the class.

Comment: @Nkosi class is now in the question

Comment: Your question has nonsense text within it because you're trying to get around the site's restriction about posting mostly code and no text. Instead of posting nonsense, you should put in the effort to explain your code and your problem in greater detail, so that your question is easier to answer. Your attempt to get around this restriction with nonsense is wrong and not fair to the volunteers who help here, and may be one reason you're question is getting down votes. Please don't do this in the future, but instead help us help you by explaining things.

Comment: What exactly do you want explained

Comment: I already explained my question but had a lot of code to post to give more background why is that a problem

Comment: @AppleGeek any feedback on the provided solution?

Comment: @Nkosi at the moment it seems part of my problem may be not the code but the fact that my app is not updating in the emulator but I will let you know when it starts working again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to match the key and that should be able to give your the property/column name that was matched

```
var key = keyEntry.Text;

var prefix = "CK_";
var church = keyQuery.FirstOrDefault();
if (church != null) {
    var type = church.GetType();
    var columnName = type.GetProperties()
        .Where(property => 
            property.Name.StartsWith(prefix) && property.GetValue(church) == key
        ).First().Name;
}
```

The prefix is used to narrow the search of the properties that were used in the filter.